# How to be an honest and good project coordinator in a corrupt and dishonest work environment?

Tags: team-management, project-team, process, management, politics

The project I am working on is given by the government organization to two private companies (A1 and A2) through a bidding process. The government is their client and the companies are vendors. I am actually an outsourced employee of government, working for them and overseeing the projects lead by these two companies (A1 & A2) but in reality I am employee of Company A1.

The project is worth US$ 80 million and nothing is done on schedule, no correct penalties are applied to the vendors in reality and no body from my government company raises fingers at them since they are now friends with the PM of companies A1 & A2. Vendors take them on foreign tours and dinners etc., buy them cars and do personal favors for them. The PM of these vendors is also responsible for giving me salary, bonuses, an experience letter, etc. But at the end of the day, I am working for the government company who is corrupt and dishonest, just like the vendors.

Whenever I send an escalation email regarding the issues of the project, suddenly I am the bad guy. When in reality, I am only doing my job. What should I do? I am just so tired.

Comment: Perhaps this should be on the [Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: I posted there. Thanks Alan :)

Also, what you think I should do? I'm a 25-year-old Project Management practitioner who is currently studying for GRE since I want to attend Grad School in USA in Spring 2019.

Answer (score 4):

If this is the US Federal government, you are in the middle of some serious fraud. This isn't something you fix, this is something you report. Call the whistleblowers hotline and look for a new job.

I think each department has its own process how to do this so you'll need to look that up.

Comment: David, I am not in the USA this is Pakistan. There are good people here with me at the company but all the senior management are corrupt. Whenever I try to do something right I get people pointing fingers at me. Basically, I am fresh in the market have experience of approximately two years and people whom I have to manage to have like decades of experience. Many times I have thought to resign but I come from a middle-class family and can't resign. I apply for new jobs,  I have applied to more than 200 jobs so that I can come out of this venomous environment but I always get rejections sadly.

Answer (score 1):

"The time is always right to do what is right"

Try to fix the problem first, have a very serious chat with the relevant people and explain the situation.

But honestly it looks like what you should do is leave. I don't see the situation improving, It's very unlikely that they'll change for the good.

Answer (score 1):

I would leave this job as soon as possible. Be careful they don't use you, so they have someone to blame for any failure later.

I don't know if there is any protection program for people telling about corruption. But be careful anyway, you never know who you can trust in this kind of cases.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen something like this before.  The most important thing is to maintain your professionalism and integrity.  Be calm and use facts and numbers wherever possible.  Don't let it become personal.  Whistleblowing may be the right thing to do, but be prepared for the personal consequences, like being fired.